# iOS 8.3 emoji unicode

Tags: ios, objective-c, emoji, ios8.3

iOS updated with few new sets of emojis - 
http://blog.emojipedia.org/apple-2015-emoji-changelog-ios-os-x

Got this - http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/full-emoji-list.html but this one also not have full list with new emojis.

I searched a lot but not get all lists with unicode any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

They are on this website : http://getemoji.com/

All with skin variations

All codes are in the table in this page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

The only missing codes are color but you can guess them

Comment: Updated link in my answer

Comment: @ gbuzogany can you please tell me how can apply color tone with U+NNNNx - eg- Apple watch i am getting \U0000231a  \U0000fe0f so how can i merge in one unicode to print apple watch back ?